# Ubuntu 18.04-4 installs in safe graphics mode only, but boots to purple screen where mouse works (NVIDIA)

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics, video

3 days ago I bougth computer parts and put them together. Ubuntu 19.10 would only install in safe graphics mode, but it worked. Then I changed my motherboard and sent the old one back to the seller. The ubuntu continue working. Then I reinstalled ubuntu 19 and now when I boot, I end up in a purple screen where the mouse works, but nothing more. Just purple and mouse. If I use nomodeset I end up in a flickering screen after boot. Flickers from black to almost black.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 will also only install/live boot in safe graphics mode, but after installation, I boot into purple screen with mouse working. I entered the grub menu and added `nomodeset` to my kernel but when I boot with it I get a flickering screen (from black to almost black) ando nothing more happens.

On more older kernels (4.15.x) I can get up to the login screen, when I put the password I enter a black screen and then HDMI loses signal.

I don't know why it worked on the older motherboard and even worke don the new one. Only after I reinstalled things it stopped working.

If I install with "download proprietary drivers" on, I get it to boot, but into the resolution 1024x768, which I can't change.

But I don't want to use proprietary drivers, I don't want to install aything proprietary in this machine, only in the virtual machines.

**UPDATE:** I remember what I did! If I plug the GPU in the first slot (and change the motherboard to use video at slot 1) I arrive at the login screen, but if I just log in, I get a black screen. However, if I change, in the small gear icon, to use Wayland instead of Xorg, I can login correctly. Then I can simply put the GPU back into slot 2 and change the motherboard to use video in slot 2. Then everything works!

**However**, I'd still like to get into the root of these problems, I found that video debugging in linux is very weak and I'd like to understand what is happening, because I really **hate** installing proprietary drivers.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and install Nvidia drivers. Without proprietary drivers not all Nvidia devices will work well enough. If you don't want them. you have an option to install all proprietary Windows ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I will use windows, but inside a VM with gpu passthrough. See my update, I remembered the ritual needed to make it work with just open source drivers. And I actually tried installing nvidia drivers, which gave a max resolution of 1024x768